# Unable to run cat command in CentOS (argument list too long)

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have a folder which has around 300k files of each file contains 2-3mb 
Now I want to run a command to find the count of char { in shell

My command:

```
nohup cat *20200119*| grep "{" | wc -l > /mpt_sftp/mpt_cdr_ocs/file.txt
```

This works fine with small number of files 
When i run in files location where I have all the files (300k files) it showing

> Argument too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*20200119*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -F -o "{" | wc -l > /mpt_sftp/mpt_cdr_ocs/file.txt
```

I have actually tested with 300,000 files of 10-character-long filenames and it is working well.

- `xargs` automatically adjusts the length of argument list fed to `grep` and we don't need to worry about it. (You can see how the `grep` command is executed by putting `-t` option to `xargs`.)
- The `-F` option drastically speeds-up the execution of `grep` to search for a fixed string, not a regex.
- The `-o` option will be needed if the character `{` appears multiple times in a line and you want to count them individually.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for correcting the typo.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of the argument list varies, but it is usually something like 128 KiB or 256 KiB.  That means you have an awful lot of files if the `*20200119*` part is overflowing the maximum argument list.  But you say "around 3 lakhs files", which is around 300,000 — each file has at least the 8-character date string in it, plus enough other characters to make the name unique, so the list of file names will be far too long for even the largest plausible 'maximum argument list size'.

Note that the `nohup cat` part of your command is not sensible (see [UUoC: Useless Use of Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/qq/11710552/15168)); you should be using `grep '{' *20200119*` to save transferring all that data down a pipe unnecessarily.  However, that too would run into problems with the argument list being too long.

You will probably have to use a variant of the following command to get the desired result without overflowing your command line:

```
find . -depth 1 -name '*20200119*' -exec grep '{' {} + | wc -l
```

This uses the feature of POSIX `find` that groups as many arguments as will fit on the command line without overflowing to run `grep` on large (but not too large) numbers of files, and then pass the output of the `grep` commands to `wc`.  If you're worried about the file names appearing in the output, suppress them with the `grep -h`.

Or you might use:

```
find . -depth 1 -name '*20200119*' -exec grep  -c -h '{' {} + |
awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```

The `grep -c -h` on macOS produces a simple number (the count of the number of lines containing at least one `{`) on its standard output for each file listed in its argument list; so too does GNU `grep`.  The `awk` script adds up those numbers and prints the result.

Using `-depth 1` is supported by `find` on macOS; so too is `-maxdepth 1` — they are equivalent.  GNU `find` does not appear to support `-depth 1`.  It would be better to use `-maxdepth 1`. POSIX `find` only supports `-depth` with no number.  You'd probably get a better error message from using `-maxdepth 1` with a `find` that only supports POSIX's rather minimal set of options than you would when using `-depth 1`.

Comment: OP says there are 3 lakhs of files. That's 300,000.

Comment: @rici — missed that; that's a lot of names all with the same 8-character date string in them.  Definitely going to overflow any plausible 'maximum argument list' size, therefore.